# Show that $|PQ|=|P'Q'|$

Tags: geometry

Let $P, P', Q, Q'$ be four different points in the euclidean plane, such that $PP'$ and $QQ'$ have different midpoints and the line $g$ passes through these midpoints and is perpendicular to $PP'$ and $QQ'$.

(a) Show that $|PQ|=|P'Q'|$.

(b) Let $P=(r,s)$ and let $g: \ ax+by+c=0$. Calculate $P'$.

$$$$

So that the line $g$ passes through the two midpoints and is perpendicular to $PP'$ and $QQ'$, the $PP'$ and $QQ'$ must be parallel, or not?

Does this mean then that $|PQ|=|P'Q'|$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So line $g$ is perpendicular to lines $PP'$ and $QQ'$ hence these lines are parallel. Moreover, $g$ is perpendicular bisector for both $PP'$ and $QQ'$ which means all points on the line $g$ are equidistant from $P$ and $P'$ and from $Q$ and $Q'$. From this we can conclude that $|PQ|=|P'Q'|$ (if $M$ is midpoint of $QQ'$, $\triangle PMQ \cong \triangle P'MQ'$).

Regarding b): 
Let $P'(p,q)$ then we have that $\frac{q-s}{p-r}=\frac{b}{a}$  or $aq-bp=as-br$
We also know that midpoint belongs to line $g$ so $a\frac{r+p}{2}+b\frac{s+q}{2}+c=0$ or $ap+bq=-2c-ar-bs$. 
Solving the system yields: $$q=\frac{a^2s-2abr-2bc-b^2s}{a^2+b^2}$$ $$p=\frac{b^2r-2abs-2ac-a^2r}{a^2+b^2}$$

Comment: To show that that the triangles $\triangle PMQ$ and $\triangle P'MQ'$ are congruent we have: $|MP|=|MP'|$, $|MQ|=|MQ'|$ and is the last condition that the angles $\angle PQM$ and $\angle P'Q'M$ are right?

Comment: We need angles $\angle PMQ$ and $\angle P'MQ'$ which are alternate interior to $\angle MPP'$ and $\angle MP'P$ and we have that $\triangle MPP'$ is isosceles.

Comment: I see!! Could you give me a hint for question (b) ? Do we use that the distance of $P$ and $P'$ from $g$ is the same?

Comment: Let $(r', s')$ be the coordinates of $P'$. Then $PP'$ is a line of the form $y-s=\frac{s'-s}{r'-r}(x-r)$ and this line must be perpendicular to $g:y=-\frac{a}{b}x-\frac{c}{b}$, so $\frac{s'-s}{r'-r}(x-r)\cdot \left (-\frac{a}{b}\right )=-1$.And the second condition is $d(P,g)=d(P',g)$, or not?

Comment: From the last equation we have \begin{align*}d(P,g)=d(P',g) \Rightarrow \frac{|ar+bs+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\frac{|ar'+bs'+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\Rightarrow |ar+bs+c|=|ar'+bs'+c|\end{align*} Do we have to take cases about the absolute values?

Comment: @MaryStar: Your approach will work, you can remove absolute value bars. I also posted my solution for b).

Comment: Thank you very much!! :-)